# Unable to set system config: Invalid Argument

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I am getting the following error message when trying to install git on windows. Can anyone help?

[image: Git install error message]

Comment: please transcribe the error text into the question

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the path by deleting the HOME variable: control panel --> edit system environment variables --> delete HOME variable. I then followed normal config instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but in case it helps someone else out, it looks like there is an apostrophe at the end of the user account (C:\Users\Tim'). It probably means that the HOME environment variable has the extra character.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be unable to find the file cause the path seems to be wrong `C:\Users\Tim'/.config/git/config`, can you modify the path anywhere ?